# How to create a query field dependent on a form field?

Tags: ms-access

I'd like to know if there is a way to make a field in a query dependent on a value from a text field on a form. Namely, I'd like to take a field from a table and multiply it by a value from a field on a form.

I tried `Input(mg): [Percent]*[forms]![frm_Formulation]![Text4]` but the field is blank when I run the query.

When I remove `[forms]![frm_Formulation]![Text4]` my percent field shows up as it should.

Cross post http://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=68017

Suggested Edit: Here is my SQL: `SELECT Tbl_Formulas.Item, Tbl_Formulas.RawMaterial, [Percent]*1257 AS [Input(mg)], Tbl_Formulas.[Quantity(kg)], Qry_Percentages.Percent
FROM Qry_Percentages INNER JOIN Tbl_Formulas ON (Qry_Percentages.Item = Tbl_Formulas.Item) AND (Qry_Percentages.[Quantity(kg)] = Tbl_Formulas.[Quantity(kg)])
WHERE (((Tbl_Formulas.Item)="a475ad"));`

I tried to recreate this instance in a new database and could not. The function works. It just doesn't work in this db...

Comment: That is correct method to reference field (or textbox control in this case). Does the field have a value? Or is it Null? Arithmetic with Null returns Null.

Comment: The form field has a value but the query is returning blank cells.

Comment: And you don't get a popup prompt to enter Text4 value? Sorry, can't explain why this fails. However, why reference a form textbox? Is this value not saved to a table? What do you want to do with the query? Is it RecordSource for a report? Cross post http://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=68017

Comment: I have a query that returns percentages for each record. I want that percentage to change based on the quantity in production (the batch size). This value isn't stored in any table. It's the craziest thing. There is no pop up asking for Text4's value. It just shows the datasheet view with blank cells.

Comment: Please show the full SQL of the query you're using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the responses. I figured out the problem. One of the relationships in my table were screwing with the query. Resetting the relationships solved the issue and now the function works properly. Thanks again, especially June7. You've helped me out many times now.